# Should to or of be used in this sentence

Tags: prepositions

Many people do not realize that they are causing disasters ______ themselves.

A. To

B. For

C. With

D. About

My teacher said the answer is A, but I think it should be B, can someone explain this to me please?
When do we use to and when do we use for ?

Answer (score 1):

[Ngram says you're both more or less right](https://books.google.com/ngrams/interactive_chart?content=cause+disaster+to%2C+cause+disaster+for&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3)

While until recently *to* was certainly the more common option, recently *for* has gained in popularity. In the end you have to go with what people actually *use*.

Although, it seems to me the the sentence itself is not idiomatic, and a native speaker would be more likely to express this in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

We would use *for* here, in Standard English.

It matches this definition of *for:*

*preposition*
3.
a. Used to indicate the recipient or beneficiary of an action:
*prepared lunch for us*

https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=For

More important, of course, is thinking about the wisdom of correcting a teacher.